# I'm having trouble with my coding on how to do it

Tags: c++

[So here's what i need to code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJFPM.jpg)

i'm having troubles on how to fix my coding, im still new to coding so please bear with me. i don't know how should i fix my coding i'm not so sure of myself whether if some of my coding is correct or it's all incorrect

[Here are the errors im getting now (Updated)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Y0CI.png)

Edit: Thanks for letting know about the EmployeeNo; (i fixed it now)

```
    float HourlyPay;
    float WeeklyHours;
    float RegularHours;
    float OvertimeHours;
    float RegularPay;
    float OvertimeWeekly;
    float OvertimePay;
    float GrossPay;
    float EmployeeNo;
    char tryAnother;
    
    
    do{
        
    system("CLS");
    printf("Please Input Employee No:");
    scanf("%f", &EmployeeNo);
    
    
    do{
        printf("No. of hours worked in a week:");
        scanf("%f", &WeeklyHours);
        
        OvertimeWeekly = WeeklyHours - 40;
        
        printf("No of hours of Overtime worked for the week");
        scanf("%d", &OvertimeWeekly);
        
        printf("Hourly Pay Rate (PHP):");
        scanf("%d", &HourlyPay);
        
if (OvertimeWeekly < 0) {
        OvertimeWeekly = 0;
}
    else if (WeeklyHours <= 40) {
            RegularHours = WeeklyHours;
            OvertimeHours = 0;
}
    else if (WeeklyHours > 40) {
            RegularHours = 40;
            OvertimeHours = WeeklyHours - 40;
}
    }
    do{
        printf("Try Another [Y/N]: ");
        scanf(" %c", &tryAnother);

    if  (tryAnother != 'N' && tryAnother != 'Y')
        printf("Invalid, Please Try Again\n");
        
        }while (tryAnother != 'N' && tryAnother != 'Y');
        }while (tryAnother != 'N' );
        
        printf("Exiting Program");
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after `EmployeeNo`.

Comment: Since you are a new contributor, please take a [tour] and read [ask]

Comment: Please refrain from making edits that invalidate correct answers.

Comment: Please roll back your previous edit, it invalidates my answer!

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
    float GrossPay;
    float EmployeeNo  // <-- You're missing a ';' here
    char tryAnother;
```